# JavaScript code not working for external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, web, frontend

I have JavaScript code that send data to backend which when I place inline then work fine but when I place in external file it does not work. Meanwhile other JavaScript is working in external file.

```
<script>
$('#submit-ajax').click(function(event) {
    console.log('working or not')
    $.post(
        '/order/detail/',
        {
            'test': 'hi i am here',
        },
        function() {
            alert( "Data Loaded: " );
        }
    )
});
</script>
```

in external file code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-ajax').click(function(event) {
        console.log('working or not')
        $.post(
            '/order/detail/',
            {
                'test': 'hi i am here',
            },
            function() {
                alert( "Data Loaded: " );
            }
        )
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the call to the file in the html file?

Comment: have you given reference of that js file in that html file which you using that button click event?

Comment: Please define "_it does not work_".

Comment: do you include your file **after** jquery?

Comment: @sri harsha <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/dynamic.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/data.js' %}"></script>

Comment: Where did you added the js file content. Either in dynamic or data.js?

Comment: @sri harsha yes sir its working for other code.

Comment: Have you got everything working now?

Comment: @sri harsha not yet

Comment: my code in data.js

Comment: Have you given the script references in head section!

Comment: @sri harsha yes in head section

Comment: @Dilshad: Can you try my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simple example,

HTML code: Relative path of external JS you need to give

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="(path of external js)\refJS.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="submit-ajax">
            click me
        </div>
</body>
```

In JS external file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-ajax').click(function(event) {
        console.log('working or not');

    });
})
```

Comment: is it necessary to give that name "refJS".

Comment: Its a JS file name which I given as dummy for reference. You need to give your data.js filename there and path of the file also.